# UWP App Google maps API gives a blank screen

Tags: google-maps, uwp

I've been trying to develop a UWP App, which uses Google maps API. So, I have created 2 projects -
1) a XAML UWP project
2) a JS UWP project
When I run both, the *map is visible in the JS project*, but not in *the XAML one*. The page **only** shows "Content goes here.", and a blank space below it in the XAML app. I have followed the documentation given in the website.
[The XAML App output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7B7d.jpg)
[The JS App output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn4CZ.jpg)

Here is the *html* -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=visualization"></script>

    <!-- mapframe references -->
    <link href="/map.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/map.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>Content goes here.</div>
    <div id="mapwindow"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the js is as follows -

```
var map;

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapdisplay'), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -187.3),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

And the CSS is -

```
html, body, #mapwindow {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the CSS look like?  Does the `map` div have a size?

Comment: Yes, it has a size "height: 100%;".
What I don't get is that it works fine with the JS UWP app and doesn't work with the XAML UWP app.

Comment: `height : 100%` only is a valid size if a containing parent element has a size.

Comment: Yes, the containing parent element has a size. I have specified the size and the element's border also appears. Only the map is blank.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I have added snapshots of the Apps for more clarity, along with the _CSS_